# the checkCredentials method of loginFormAuthenticator returns false

Tags: symfony5

hello I have a registration page allowing a user to log in if the registration is valid he is redirected to the login page but if he enters the same password symfony returns invalid credentials.
registration method
"'

```
public function inscription(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, ValidatorInterface $validator, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
        {
            $utilisateur= new Users();
            $form= $this->createForm(UserType::class, $utilisateur);
            $utilisateur->setPassword( $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($utilisateur, $utilisateur->getPassword()));
                $form->handleRequest($request);
                if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
                    
                {
                    $utilisateur -> setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
                    $em -> persist($utilisateur);
                    $em->flush();   
                    $errors = $validator->validate($utilisateur);
                    
                    if (count($errors) > 0) {
                        $errorsString = (string) $errors;

                        return new Response($errorsString);
                    }

                    $this->addFlash('success', 'Votre inscription a réussi!');
                    $this->addFlash('success', 'Vous pouvez maintenant vous connectez!');
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_login');
                    
                }
            return $this->render('sunutontine/inscription.html.twig' ,[
                'controller_name' => 'SunuController',
                'formUser' => $form->createView() ,
            ]);
        }
```

'"
loginFormAuthenticator.php
"'

```
 public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }
```

"'

it seems that the password encoded at the time of registration is different from the one stored by checkCredentials.

Answer (score 0):

try to chnage order of lines , put $form->handleRequest($request); just after $form->createForm(): like so the object User will be filled with data of the submitted form

```
$utilisateur= new Users();
$form= $this->createForm(UserType::class, $utilisateur);
$form->handleRequest($request);

$utilisateur->setPassword( $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($utilisateur, $utilisateur->getPassword()));
```

Names of inputs in twig login must be the same in LoginFormAuthenticator

```
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
        'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
        'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
    ];
    $request->getSession()->set(
        Security::LAST_USERNAME,
        $credentials['email']
    );

    return $credentials;
}
```

Comment: hello hous I tried the method you suggested but it doesn't work even though I did a dump to see if the password encoded by checkCredentials and the database password but it's totally different

Comment: does the password is encoded in the database ? can you show the login form ? maybe the names of inputs doesn't match with the loginFormAuthenticator

Comment: yes the password encoding is done automatically
in my login form I just changed the names to French
could you help me i don't know how to attach a file to show you

Comment: Names of inputs must be the same in LoginFormAuthenticator , $request->request->get('password') and othres. I have updated my response